# Como executar uma função em um componente e afetar outro componente - Angular 6

Tags: typescript, javascript-eventos, angular-6, angularjs-components

Gostaria de saber como posso através de um componente afetar outro componente no angular 6.
Esses componentes não são pai e filho. São distintos.

```
<app-navegacao></app-navegacao>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Onde está Open/Closed Quotes é a minha barra de navegação: ""

E onde tem a tabela fica meu outro componente que faz parte de um router-outlet:

[image: Imagem 1]

quero executar o evento associado ao botão verde e emitir os valores para a minha barra de navegação

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um Serviço que possui um BehaviorSubject ? No componente da table você insere conteúdo no Subject, e no componente de navegação você da um subscribe no mesmo... já tentou?

Comment: Não sabia dessa possibilidade. Como funciona isso?

Comment: Vou formular uma resposta para te exemplificar.

Comment: Minha opinião: A barra ficaria no componente pai e o componente debaixo entraria através da navegação através do `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Assim basta você usar [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) pra notificar o componente pai sempre que algo acontecer no componente filho.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma @Service com um BehaviorSubject. O BehaviorSubject contém o valor que precisa ser compartilhado com outros componentes, ele ao menos tempo é Observador e Observável o mesmo pode receber e emitir os valores atuais.

Você irá precisar uma Service com um atributo do tipo BehaviorSubject, no meu exemplo criei o mesmo com o tipo numero e um valor padrão 0, como abaixo:

```
@Injectable()
export class QuoteService {
  public openQuotes = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

setOpenQuote(quotes : number){
   this.openQuotes.next(quotes);
}
}
```

No componente da Table será o lugar onde irá pegar os dados, e enviá-los para o BehaviorSubject, então você precisa injetar a Service no componente da Table, e no método chamado pelo botão verde, você irá enviar os dados:

```
construtor(
   quoteService : QuoteService 
){}

acaoBotaoVerde(){
   this.quoteService.setOpenQuote(quotesOpened);
}
```

E no componente de navegação você simplesmente irá fazer um subscribe para ficar monitorando caso as informações mudem:

```
construtor(
   quoteService : QuoteService 
){}

this.quotesOpen = this.quoteService.openQuotes.subscribe(
   (quotes) => {
     return quotes;
   }
);
```

Claro, esse código pode ser otimizado, mas ajuda você ter uma ideia do que utilizar.

Comment: Valeu mano. Vou testá-lo aqui.
Se não for abusar da sua boa vontade.. gostaria de saber se você possui um material onde eu posso estudar rxjs e como saber se uma requisição foi feita e se deu certo ou não esta requisição.

Começando agora a desenvolver em front e back e isso está me atrapalhando.

Comment: Amigo confesso que o conteúdo em PT-Br é bem escasso, mas para rxjs mais especificamente os Observables, recomendo esse artigo aqui, nele você vai ver sobre os métodos de retorno, then, error e etc... https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-rxjs-observable-com-angular/

Answer (score -2):

Abaixo vou passar um exemplo bem simples de como disparar e ouvir eventos de diferentes contextos, será descrito o que fazer em cada contexto.

CONTEXTO - Serviço do componente do botão verde:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'; //import necessario

public eventoEmit = new EventEmitter<boolean>(); // seu emissor de evento

public Click_BotaoVerde()
{
    //demais ações 
    this.eventoEmit.emit(true); // emitindo o evento
}
```

CONTEXTO - Component menu

```
constructor(private _btnVerdeService: BtnVerdeService){

  this._btnVerdeService.eventoEmit.subscribe(x => {
      // Aqui você já esta ouvindo os eventos do btn verde
    });
}
```